# How to input characters and read them as numers?

Tags: c

I'm a C beginner;
I'm making a simple program about ''battleship/naval battle'' game:
As you can see in the screenshot, the program will ask to the user to input a number for the row, and the same things goes for the column;
I wanted to let the user input a character and associate it with the correct column. How could I proceed?

[image: See yellow-marked output]

CODE:
[..]

```
if (CAMPO[row][column] == 3 || CAMPO[row][column] == 2 || CAMPO[row][column] == 1)
{
    ATTACCHI[row][column]='X'; //SHIP HIT!;
    printf("\nSHIP HIT!\n");
    TENTATIVI--;                                  
    CASELLE_NAVI--;                              
    if (num_suggerimenti>0)
    {
        suggerimenti(CAMPO,riga_attacco,colonna_attacco);
        num_suggerimenti--;                    
    }
    printf("\nRIEPILOGO DEGLI ATTACCHI EFFETTUATI:\n\n");
    visualizza_attacchi(ATTACCHI);
}
else
{
    ATTACCHI[row][column]='/'; //SHIP MISS!;
    printf("\nSHIP MISS!\n");
    TENTATIVI--;
    if (num_suggerimenti>0)
    {
        suggerimenti(CAMPO,riga_attacco,colonna_attacco);
        num_suggerimenti--;
    }
    printf("\nRIEPILOGO DEGLI ATTACCHI EFFETTUATI:\n\n");
    visualizza_attacchi(ATTACCHI);
}
```

[..]

HERE IS THE QUESTION:

```
printf("Insert row number (0-9):\n");
scanf("%d",&row);
printf("Inserisci column number (A-L):\nA=0 B=1 C=2 D=3 E=4 F=5 G=6 H=7 I=8 L=9\n");
scanf("%d",&column);
```

**sorry took some minutes to translate it**

Comment: Show at least the code which made what we see in the screenshot, please.

Comment: Read a letter and subtract `'A'` from it.

Comment: Read a string. Check it has two characters, one a letter and one a digit, both in range.

Comment: @Yunnosch code uploaded, sorry for not being clear

Comment: @barmar could you please show me an example? thanks

Comment: I once also wrote code in my own language. I gave up on that. I do not understand your language; therefore it's hard to understand your code, especially as you use functions and variables that you haven't provided definitions for.

Comment: @Andreas yeah I noticed that. I'm gonna give up on that too, you're right. Sorry for not being clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use `fgets()` to read whole lines of input, then use `sscanf()` to extract from it. For the column you can use `%c` format to extract the letter. Then subtract `'A'` from it to convert it to a number.

```
char line[10];
printf("Insert row number (0-9):\n");
fgets(stdin, line, sizeof line);
sscanf(line, "%d", &row);
printf("Inserisci column letter (A-L):\n");
fgets(stdin, line, sizeof line);
char column_letter;
sscanf(line, "%c", &column_letter);
column = column_letter - 'A';
```